# Python firestore collection query order by document_id

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

We can order a collection query by documentId in javascript,
`.orderBy(firebase.firestore.FieldPath.documentId())`

How is this done in python, cannot seem to find a similar object *(field_path.document_id)* in the python SDK reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done this way

```
from google.cloud.firestore_v1.field_path import FieldPath
.order_by(FieldPath.document_id())
```

It is found in the code [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/blob/99ee129166a6301b5d2800b681088687ed3ebb25/google/cloud/firestore_v1/field_path.py#L385)

Comment: How do I do the same in descending order ?

Comment: @Mateen-Hussain https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data